# Can you enable a color picker on safari dev tools?

Tags: safari, safari-web-inspector

Is there a way to enable the color picker on safari dev tools web inspector? Or even change the format of the color from RGB? I know you can do both of these on Google Chrome (see second screenshot)

[image: Safari Browser Dev Tools Screenshot]

[image: Google Chrome Dev Tools Screenshot]

Comment: I don't believe there's such a built-in feature in Safari, but if you're on Mac you can use an app called "Digital Colour Meter" that you can find in Utilities. More info:
https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/quickest-way-to-find-hex-color-in-safari.1060264/

Comment: @bdrnglm answer should be the accepted one. It did the job for me. Thanks!!! I still didn't quite get how to save to clipboard the values of the colours I'm hovering over but that's another topic.